# Docker CMD not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I started up my custom mysql-server image-based docker container today only to find that it isn't running my CMD commands. It was fine up until today. This is the Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for the db service
FROM mysql/mysql-server:latest

RUN mkdir /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts

COPY ./db_setup.sql .
CMD ["mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword", "<", "/scripts/db_setup.sql"]
```

And this is how I'm initializing the container:

```
  db:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: 'db'
    restart: on-failure
```

What's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docker-compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#command), the `command` in the docker-compose file overrides the docker `CMD` defined in the docker file.

If you want to have a command in the dockerfile and arguments in the docker-compose file (which seem to be what you are trying to do), then you must use an `entrypoint` in your docker file and a `command` in your docker-compose.